# dbms_output.put_line not working properly with a cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I was trying to print numbers from 1 to 100 by using a cursor, through dbms_output command, but an error shows up, saying "ORA-06550: line 6, column 1: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'"

Then I tried to do the same by using a table.
For that I used the following query:

insert into numb select rownum r from dual connect by rownum<= 100;

But the error still persists.

This is the code I am executing for dual table:

Declare

```
cursor c_num is select rownum n from dual connect by rownum <=100;
begin 
    for i in c_num
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('Number is '||i);

    end loop;
end;
```

For user made table numb:

Declare

```
cursor c_num is select num from numb;
begin 
    for i in c_num
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('Number is '||i);    
    end loop;
end;
```

Please let me know what's wrong with this code.

Answer (score 1):

`i` is a record type.  You cannot concatenate a string ("Number is ") to a record type.  Try this instead:

```
dbms_output.put_line('Number is '||to_char(i.num));
```

Comment: @dingobingo You're welcome.  If your question has been answered, please consider accepting the answer.  That way, your question stops showing up as "unanswered".